# jQuery find element with class name which is added dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have  a navigation which is  listed dynamically with PHP.

```
<nav id='navs'>
@foreach($element as $val)
<a data-prop={{$val->id}}>$val->name</a>
@endforeach
</nav>
```

The html :
[image: html]
The highlighted the  tags are listed dynamically

I have a JS script, when we click on the navbar element then we add .selected class to the  tag.
When the page is loaded the first  tag  has .selected class.

I need a JS code  to find the data-prop attribute value for the elements with .selected class.
I tried:

```
 var d=  $("#navs .selected").attr('data-prop');
```

but  the d variable is undefined. Any suggestion? I also tried  the .find() method.

Comment: Given the description of how the navigation is structured then your JS should work. If it's not then we need to see a more complete example of the HTML and JS with a demo of the issue. Also make sure to check the console in devtools for errors which may be affecting the logic.

Comment: Maybe there is no element with the class `selected` in your `navs`? So your selector can't select any element and `.attr("data-prop")` resolves to `undefined`.

Comment: you should you put ' in data-prop. Anyway you can try also with $("#navs .selected").data('prop')

Comment: Look at this line `<a data-prop={{$val->id}}>$val->name</a>`, where is `class` attribute? I see you are selecting it as `.selected`!

Comment: Your code working fine : https://jsfiddle.net/wayhx0qe/

Comment: @ServingQuarantineperiod But this navigation is not listed dynamically.

Comment: @TariqulIslam  Please read the description once again.

Comment: @Ogod I inspected the page, I have element with that classname

Comment: @dev198742  kindly read first comment under your question. Please provide us ___more complete example of the HTML and JS with a demo of the issue___

Comment: Make sure `var d=  $("#navs .selected").attr('data-prop');` this line gets executed after `whatever` code you have for that dynamically `.selected` class assignment.

Comment: You can execute this code `var d=  $("#navs .selected").attr('data-prop');` in the console of your browsers DevTools and inspect the result. If `d` isn't undefined anymore it might be a timing problem (like @Tariqul Islam  mentioned).

Comment: Thanks for help for all you! I figured out what is the problem, and posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was. I have a script which is  adding the class name .selected to the  tags, the problem is that  it executed AFTER my script, where I wanted to find the element with the .selected class.

So my code is working:

```
 var d=  $("#navs .selected").attr('data-prop');
```

Answer (score 1):

For the given example one could to the following:

first get an array of all related elements

```
 d = $("#navs > a");
```

And then iterate and get your desired attributes:

```
for (index = 0; index < d.length; ++index) {
    console.log(d[index].getAttribute("id"));
}
```

... the given example prints the `ID` attribute instead your custom attribute (`data-prop`)

Comment: Its okay, but how I can  get the  element with the .selected class name?

Comment: instead of "id" you simply could get the "class" attribute and check if the value is equals to "selected". Keep in mind that may multiple classes can be assigned.